# Innocent Farming

Tags: disgaea-5

I finally completed the main story of Disgaea 5 also known as the extended tutorial and I have spent most of the story collecting innocents from items that I have found, specifically statistician which increases XP earned when it is equipped.

I have just really started to use the innocent farm and dumping prisoners into the squad for it but I am still confused as to how to maximize growth from the farm. From what I have read I need to take my unsubduded innocents and place them on an item and go into the item world for that item and kill the innocents when I find them after switching the route to innocent enhance which will subdue it and raise its level a tiny bit because of the route.

I know I can combine subdued innocents of the same type to get a higher level capped innocent but the levels do not go very high and some innocent types have insanely high max levels. I know I can then use these higher capped innocents to breed new ones with the higher level caps, but this process seems extremely slow even with my high ranked innocent squad, gaining on average one or two levels every 10 battles or so. (Note I do not have innocents breed are automatically subdued yet which I am frantically working on getting.)

My question is how can I speed up the growth of my innocents because the rate they are currently gaining levels in the farm is extremely slow, and I need my level 900 Statistician for grind to level 9999.

Comment: Oh boy, this is a fun grind.

Comment: @Vemonus You can't have Disgaea without the grind can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much have the method to this grind down. For a reference, [this guide](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/835980-disgaea-5-alliance-of-vengeance/72651247) outlines the strategy I followed to get my 900 Statistician.

> You need to upgrade the farm so the new innocents it makes are subdued.
>
> 1) place 2 statisticians in the farm
>
> 2) once a 3rd appears, remove 1 red and make sure the yellow subdued one is on that farm with another statistician, red or yellow.
>
> 3) once it breeds a 2nd yellow, subdued statistician make sure you only have 2 yellow subdued ones on the farm
>
> 4) every time a new one is born, remove it and the first one onto an item, go into the manager, combine them, and then put them back on the farm. Rinse repeat.

Unfortunately, this is Disgaea, which means there is no easy path to maxing characters. However, once you start getting better Statisticians, you effectively get a snowball effect where you start producing better and better Innocents, to the point where you will be able to get multiple 900 Statisticians in no time (after the initial grind, that is).

Your top priority should be to upgrade your Innocent Farm to spawn subdued Innocents to take out the time required to subdue them. Then, just keep doing what you're doing. Combine the spawned Innocents with the parents to keep powering them up so that they produce better Innocents.

Answer (score 0):

Subduing innocents is a *big* bonus (2x). Doing it on the Innocent route is even better (4x). Doing that with a character in the Innocent Hunting squad doubles it again (8x). Finally, you can use Sages to manipulate the Geo panels and, if you are lucky, get an Innocent panel to throw the Innocent on top of before killing it (16x) - but I'm usually not too worried about the last one. At least while starting out, this is a much faster strategy than upgrading your farm to auto-subdue, because that only gives you the 2x bonus (if even that).

You can also put a high-level single-stat innocent in the farm together with one of the lower-cap innocents (Professional, Statistician, etc.) to birth new ones - the child's level is based on both parents. I haven't tried this with Statisticians, as I was mostly past farming those already when I started with other innocents.